# Can you use helper functions inside R6 objects?

Tags: r, r6

I'm trying to avoid repetition inside an R6 object. There are calculated/derived values that must be updated each time one of the inputs is updated.

The `Cube` object below demonstrates the problem. If I update any of `width`, `height` or `depth`, it follows that `volume` must be updated.

In this case, the formula is trivial, but in real-world cases that won't always be the case.  It is possible to store the knowledge of `volCalc` someplace, and to allow `set_width` to use that function to update `volume` when they are updated?

Right now, i can create the object using the object code below:

```
R> cc <- Cube$new(width = 5, height = 6, depth = 7)
```

but it breaks on update

```
R> cc$set_width(10)
Error in volCalc(self$width, self$height, self$depth) : 
  could not find function "volCalc"
```

As you can see, I put the knowledge of how to calculate the volume of a cube (`volCalc`) in two places; but alas `cc$set_width` and friends cannot find it...

```
Cube <- R6Class("Cube",
  public = list(
    width = NULL,
    height = NULL,
    depth = NULL,
    volume = NULL,

    initialize = function(width, height, depth) {
      self$width <- width
      self$height <- height
      self$depth <- depth

      volCalc = function(W, H, D) W * H * D

      self$volume <- volCalc(width, height, depth)
    },

    volCalc = function(W, H, D) {
      self$volume <- W * H * D
      invisible(self)
    },    

    set_width = function(nWidth) {
      self$width <- nWidth
      volCalc(self$width, self$height, self$depth)
      invisible(self)
    },

    set_height = function(nHeight) {
      self$height <- nHeight
      volCalc(self$height, self$height, self$depth)
      invisible(self)
    },

    set_depth = function(nDepth) {
      self$depth <- nDepth
      volCalc(self$depth, self$depth, self$depth)
      invisible(self)
    }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell your class where to find `volCalc`. It will find it in `self`. So all you need to do is make the internal calls to `volCalc` be `self$volCalc`. Then you can do this:

```
cc <- Cube$new(width = 5, height = 6, depth = 7)
cc
#> <Cube>
#>   Public:
#>     clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
#>     depth: 7
#>     height: 6
#>     initialize: function (width, height, depth) 
#>     set_depth: function (nDepth) 
#>     set_height: function (nHeight) 
#>     set_width: function (nWidth) 
#>     volCalc: function (W, H, D) 
#>     volume: 210
#>     width: 5

cc$set_width(10)
cc
#> <Cube>
#>   Public:
#>     clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
#>     depth: 7
#>     height: 6
#>     initialize: function (width, height, depth) 
#>     set_depth: function (nDepth) 
#>     set_height: function (nHeight) 
#>     set_width: function (nWidth) 
#>     volCalc: function (W, H, D) 
#>     volume: 420
#>     width: 10
```

Comment: Ahh ... and with a bit of fiddling i see that it also works in the `initialize` function; once i removed the `invisible(self)` line of the function.